# Query results in 'Syntax error at end of input' (java / Postgres)

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I receive an error which I don't understand.
This is the part of the query in the WHERE clause which results in an error.

```
WHERE 
CASE so.console_role
WHEN 'NONE' THEN so.orderid = '512' 
ELSE so.console_id IN (select console_id from service_order where so.orderid 
= '512')
```

**Error:**

> ERROR:  syntax error at end of input LINE 118:

Have someone an idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A case expression is exactly that an *expression* that returns a *value*, it doesn't work like `if`.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: BTW, your case has no `end`.

Comment: You need an `end` statement with this notation. Just a typo...

Comment: Argh stupid! I forgot the END. 
Thanks for the quick reply guys. 

I will look at the and/or construction, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `case` expressions in the `where` clause.  Use boolean logic:

```
WHERE (so.console_role = 'NONE' AND so.orderid = '512'
      ) OR
      (so.console_role <> 'NONE' AND so.console_id IN (select console_id from service_order where so.orderid = '512')
      )
```

Note that this does not take `NULL` values into account for `so_console_role`, although that is trivial to add.

Also, I suspect the logic in the second part is not correct, and you intend:

```
WHERE (so.console_role = 'NONE' AND so.orderid = '512'
      ) OR
      (so.console_role <> 'NONE' AND so.console_id IN (select so2.console_id from service_order so2 where so2.orderid = '512')
      )
```

The `where` clause in your version of the subquery is referring to `so` in the outer query.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! Why is a 'case' expression not recommended?

Comment: @MauriceJansen . . . A `case` expression pretty much blocks efforts by the optimizer.  In addition, boolean logic is sufficient to express the logic.  In some rare cases, you want a `case` expression to control the order of evaluation, but that is unusual.

Comment: Clearly! Thanks again for the help and explanation.